# Why can't I attach TFS to a Project Collection that was restored to SQL Server (I think) correctly?

Tags: sql-server

We tried moving a TFS Project Collection from one TFS 2010 server to another.

1. Detached the collection in TFS Console on source server
2. Backed up the collection, Tfs_DefaultCollection, in SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition
3. DBA restored the Collection to a new database, Tfs_MyCollection, to the SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, R2, instance used by the target TFS Server.
4. TFS Administrator attempted to attach to the target server.

TFS adminisitrator received the following error message.

> TF254078: No attachable databases were found on the following instance
>   of SQL Server: MyServerName. Verify that both the name of the server
>   and the name of the instance are correct and that the database was
>   properly detached using the detach command in the Team Foundation
>   Administration Console.

I assmumed we did not need to prepare the database instance in the target server since it already contained a TFS Project Collection.
I assumed that going up in a SQL Server edition was acceptable.

Are my assumptions valid?
What could be the cause of not being able to attach to the new TFS Server?

btw, I created this post on ServerFault originally [Mirror in Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/392725/why-cant-i-attach-tfs-to-a-project-collection-that-was-restored-to-sql-server-c), but it generated very little interest there.

Comment: did you change the name of the database you restored in the target SQL server? does the target TFS server already have a TPC of the same name than the one you've backuped and you tried to restore?

Comment: @Nock: yes the restore was done with a new database name, Tfs_MyCollection (name changed to protect the innocent  :) This name is different than the only other TPC on this target instance, which has the name Tfs_DefaultCollection.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, We are talking about backing up the database to .bak file and restoring onto another SQL Server instance. When you restore, SQL Server asks for the database name to be restored to. So at least in SQL Server this is not a problem. Why would it be a problem in TFS?

Comment: What you described should work, so we're missing something... Check these posts: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2010/09/15/how-to-rename-a-tfs-collection.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2010/11/12/how-to-rename-a-tfs-collection-part-2.aspx maybe they'll be helpful.

Comment: With SQL Management Studio make sure there's the new database restored with the name you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure both the TFS service level and SQL server versions match the previous server.
You can verify this information using *SQL Management Studio* > `Databases` > `Tfs_Configuration` *or* `Tfs_DefaultCollection` > `Properties` > `Extended Properties`

Note these properties:

```
TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION 10.0.40219.1
TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION  Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 (SP1)
TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL   Tfs2010.SP1.KB2182621.P#1
```

Also note the SQL version under `<database instance name>` > `Properties` > `General`

```
Version             10.50.2500.0
```

Comment: That's It! I was careless to think both being TFS 2010 was sufficient. My TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION was 10.0.30319.1 and my TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL was Tfs 2010.RTM on the source server.

Comment: ...oh and TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION was Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 (RTM)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...

1. Actions to perform on TFS 2010

   1.1 Using the TFS console "Detach" the collection from the "TFS server"
   1.2 Using the SQl Manager "Detach" the database for the corresponding TFS collection
2. Actions to perform on TFS 2012

   2.1 Using the SQl Manager "attach" the database for the corresponding TFS collection
   2.2 Make sure to give the TFS user account/s access to the database otherwise the TFS server will not be able to access it.
   2.3 Using the TFS console "attach" the collection to the "TFS server"

Comment: Although interesting, this is not exactly the problem I had. I was using an RTM version of TFS 2010 that could not be migrated to the release version of TFS 2010. At least there was not a proscribed method of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Just as additional information...

KMoraz if right. Both TFS and SQL Server are made to run together at the same version (The Major version).

To explain how you probably get there is:

- You made a backup of you TFS database
- You upgraded TFS version (TFS migrated your database - it became another version)
- You restored your backup (TFS database version is now older that TFS version itself)