# TFS 2018 Split Project Collection

Tags: tfs, devops

I currently have SQL server version: 
**Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64)**

TFS 2018 installed on a differen server version: **Team Foundation Server 2018 (16.122.27102.1 (Tfs2018))**

I've followed the article here [Split Team Project Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/split-team-project-collection) which applies to TFS 2015 and 2013 as i cannot find anything for 2018.

In step [Step-2C-Attach-The-Renamed-Collection-Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/split-team-project-collection#2-c-attach-the-renamed-collection-database) i am getting the error TF254078

[image: TFS254078 Error]

I've ensured that the Project Collection was taken offline and detached before performing the backup as thats what the majority of questions and sites are saying (see below)

1. [Example 1](https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/tag/tfs/)
2. [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822543/why-cant-i-attach-tfs-to-a-project-collection-that-was-restored-to-sql-server)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Below is my Tfs_Configuration database. The original Team Project Collection (Tfs_Software) and the new collection which is a copy of software (Tfs_Lawyerly)

```
-- Configuration Database
TFS_DATABASE_TYPE   Configuration
TFS_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE OnPremises
TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION 16.122.27102.1
TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION  Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2018
TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL   Dev16.M122.5


-- Lawyerly
TFS_DATABASE_TYPE   Collection
TFS_DATAIMPORT_COLLECTIONID b2511dcb-83cd-4b1e-b024-653f2f0a222f
TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION 16.122.27102.1
TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION  Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2018
TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL   Dev16.M122.5
TFS_SNAPSHOT_COLLECTIONID   1b492594-e5e4-48e1-8f78-1c0426db79d3
TFS_SNAPSHOT_STATE  Complete

-- Software
TFS_DATABASE_TYPE   Collection
TFS_DATAIMPORT_COLLECTIONID b2511dcb-83cd-4b1e-b024-653f2f0a222f
TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION 16.122.27102.1
TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION  Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2018
TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL   Dev16.M122.5
```

Comment: Are you sure the database is from the same version of TFS 2018? If you installed TFS 2018 RTM and the database is from TFS 2018 Update 1, you won't be able to attach it.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, Yes i'm pretty sure it's from the same version of TFS 2018. I only have one version of TFS running and i took the backup only just today. I was able to restore the original collection again but i'm looking to split it.

I've editing my question with some more info regarding the database.

Comment: Wait, you want to attach it to the **same** TFS instance?

Comment: Yes i'm splitting The one project collection Software into 2 so, Software (original) and then Lawyerly(second) I will obviously have to delete the projects from Lawyerly that i don't want but yes same instance, so versioning shouldnt be an issue